# Custom Annotation works only for ElementType.METHOD

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop, aspect

I'm practising with customs annotations and I want to create a custom annotation that set a Math.random() value to an @Entity field (I know that I can do this in the constructor but I want to do with an annotation)

1. My Annotation:

   `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target(ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR) 
   public @interface SetRandomPin {}`

2.My Aspect

```
@Around("@annotation(com.testingAnnotations.annotattions.SetRandomPin)")
            public void setUserPin(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws NoSuchMethodException {....}
}
```

In my @Entity when I put @SetRandomPin in the constructor, the method setUserPin is not firing.

Only If I change to ElementType.METHOD and I move my annotation to the UserService.class the method is firing.

I'm stuck here and I can't understand why is working with an ElmentType but not with another one.

Answer (score 0):

Default Spring AOP doesn't offer constructor interception or private/protected methods. You can do it using AspectJ.

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)

> If your interception needs include method calls or even constructors within the target class, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework.

Comment: I'm assuming that AspectJ is enabled with the annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy but i'm stuck in the same

Comment: Don't assume, better read the documentation. That annotation is for Spring AOP, despite the "AspectJ" part in its name. But it also says "AutoProxy" and only Spring AOP uses proxies, AspectJ does not need them. Scroll down in the AOP documentation a bit until you find the [AspectJ load-time weaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) chapter.